# Taylor Polynomial for Odd Degree

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor polynomial of degree 2n + 1 at 0 of the function

$$f(x)=\int_0^x\frac{sint}{t}dt$$

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $$f(t)=\int _0^x\left(\frac{\sum \frac{(-1)^nt^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}{t}\right)dt=\int _0^x\left(\sum \frac{(-1)^nt^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\right)dt=\sum \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)((2n+1)!)}$$ Hope it will help